# Can someone please translate a German inscription into English?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

My son's birthday is next week. For a gift, I bought a 150-year-old German drinking glass with a hand-painted image of a man bowling, and an inscription below. It reads:

> "Gut Holz ein Hoch dem Kegelsport, Halt ihn, zum Wohl sei unser Wort!"

I believe it is a "*wish to have a good game*", and a *"toast or cheers to the high bowler."*
The last part seems to be about "*holding or keeping him, and maybe something about being good as our word.*" It is very confusing to someone who doesn't speak German. Could someone please translate?

Comment: Having someone to send you the answer is IMO not the way, this forum is meant to be used.

Comment: Personal data removed. You will receive a notification displayed in the page's head when new answers arrive. You may also subscribe to the questions's rss feed.

Comment: @AndroidRookie Even though he's new to the site, he has shown some effort and it's a tough phrase, as can be seen from your answer.

Comment: @Carlster I totally agree, I only meant that he should (in future) leave out thing like "send it to ...". the question itself is IMO totally fine, I even upvoted it

Comment: @AndroidRookie I'm so sorry, that was edited out before I came here!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, let me mention that there are some differences between modern "bowling" and "Kegeln" (e.g. number of pins), but in the following I will use the translation "bowling" for "Kegeln". Maybe a more appropriate is "skittles" or "ninepins" according to dict.leo.org.

> Gut Holz

Literally "good wood". "Holz" is a bowling term for the pins. "Gut Holz" is a bowlers greeting. It uses the non-inflected version of the adjective "gut". One would expect an inflected form ("Gutes Holz") but non-inflected forms are sometimes found in idiomatic expressions.

> Ein Hoch dem Kegelsport

"Hoch" literally means "high". As a noun it means "a cheer", "cheers". The dative-construction "dem Kegelsport" can be translated as "to bowling sports".

> Halt ihn!

Literally "hold it" (ihn=male=der Kegelsport; it=neuter=bowling sports); the meaning is "preserve/conserve bowling".

> Zum Wohle sei unser Wort

"Zum Wohle" literally means "to/for the good"; it is a drinking toast like "Cheers!". "sei unser Wort" is "Konjunktiv I" and can be translated as "be our word". The whole phrase: "Our word be for the good."

Comment: The same "gut" can be found in "auf gut Glück", "gut Ding will Weile haben" and "gut Teil". +1.

Comment: Although the "gut" in "gut Teil" is not nearly as idiomatic.

Comment: Maybe "Halt ihn!" doesn't relate to bowling but rather to the glass (ihn = den Bierkrug) itself?

Comment: That's possible; but I guess it is more likely that the pronoun referes to something mentioned afore. Additionally, I would expect a "hoch", if the pronoun did reference to the glass/jug.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it means something along these lines:

"*Cheers to bowling, preserve it, our word for its good*"

But I have no clue on the

> "Gut Holz"

part. It means something like "Good Wood", but its likely to be an idiomatic expression.

Comment: "Gut Holz" is a common greeting in bowling. It means "good game" or "good luck". It is often used before the game starts as a greeting to welcome the arriving players.

Comment: Oh, and the "Holz" in that expression refers to the bowling pin.